# How do I remove part of a string that starts with +

Tags: r, string, split

data in my damage column will sometimes appear as 43808+5%. I wanna remove the +5% (sometimes it goes as high as +25%) to isolate the damage number. I also want to put the % modifier in its own column eventually, but the string data is inconsistent about where it displays the +xx%, so a fixed number of characters doesn't work.

I want to do something along the lines of

```r
batlog2[c('damage', 'modifier')] <- str_split_fixed(batlog2$damage,'+', 2)
```

but its throwing an error with the +

Comment: `stringr` interprets patterns as regular expressions by default and in regex `+` happens to carry a special meaning.  For literal `+` it should be escaped (`"\\+"`), or better yet -- to interpret pattern as a fixed string, enclose it in `fixed()` or `coll()` :   `batlog2[c('damage', 'modifier')] <- str_split_fixed(batlog2$damage, coll('+'), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `read.csv`.

```
cbind(d, read.csv(text=d$v, sep='+', header=FALSE, na.strings='') |> setNames(c('dam', 'mod')))
#           v         sth   dam  mod
# 1     43808 -0.85090759 43808 <NA>
# 2  43808+5% -2.41420765 43808   5%
# 3 43808+25%  0.03612261 43808  25%
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- data.frame(v=c('43808', '43808+5%', '43808+25%'), sth=rnorm(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr` has a nice utility for this:

```
library(tidyr)
batlog2 |> 
tidyr::separate_wider_delim(
  damage, 
  delim = "+",
  names = c("damage", "modifier")
)
```

(with older versions of `tidyr` you can use `separate()` instead of `separate_wider_delim()`)